# How to connect to database using dynamic data in zend framework 3

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework3

I have a database where I have data about other databases.

I need to use this data to connect to other database in zend framework 3, but I only know how to config database connections in local.php file.

There's another way to make a database connection? Is it possible to connect using those dynamic data?

Comment: Create some sort of service which provides connections dynamically, and thus creates them based on a config request (possibly cached as well)? More to the point, what have you tried thus far? Ideas, (pseudo-)code, etc?

Comment: I found this link https://linkstraffic.net/on-demand-doctrine-database-switch-with-zend-3/ e tried to apply to my project, but for some reason the function onMergeConfig doesn't execute.

My project was with a attempt to implement a cache system, that didn't work before, so I commented those lines, but it still not pass through onMergeConfig.

By now I create a container to storage all the data I need when my user log in, and created the onMergeConfig in my Module.php to insert all of them in my configuration.

I tried to put a die at the function start, but is not been called

Comment: What I need to do is create a system that manage others websites, this website's data are at my database and I need to connect on demand, without the need to configure the connection on local.php or any other file

Comment: did you add `implements ConfigProviderInterface` to the class?

Comment: Now I add this implementation to my Module.php but it still not passing through onMergeConfig.
I'm reading ConfigProviderInterface documentation to see if there's other details

Comment: Does onMergeConfig function actually exists on zf3? I`ve found a lot of documentation of zf2 about it, but only a few things about it in zf3

Comment: Ah shit sorry missed that. No I do not think it does. As a side note, why don't you create a service to get this data from the database for you? I'm assuming you have at least one configured for the purpose of serving your management application. As such, having a "ClientApplicationConnectionService" or something of the sorts makes sense. This application would in turn be used by a service that does actual managing ("ResetCredentials", "CreatePage", whatever actions in that service, which all use the "CACS" service). Or something rather.

Comment: That management service would also contain a caching service (you tried that you said, I have a simple example [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-country), [config file](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-country/blob/master/config/cache.config.php.dist), [service file](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-country/blob/master/src/Service/LocaleOptionsManager.php), [factory file](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-country/blob/master/src/Factory/Service/LocaleOptionsManagerFactory.php)). This demo setup could contain requirements for other services.

Comment: AUHSUA It's ok, thanks for always helping me ˆˆ'
I'm going to study the caching service after I finish some tasks and try to implement it, I'm gonna give a feedback about it later xD
About the connection, now I config my db connections on local.php, how could I create a new one with a factory? Despite the login, my application doesn't have other services, so I don't know exactly when and how to use then instead of a controller